# Can handling pygame keyboard input and collision-check results be done tersely?

Tags: python, pygame

how can I improve this?
for loops? zip? enumerate? It seems like it could be shortened, but Im not sure how.

```
if checkcollide(plrx,plry) == True:
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                plry += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                plrx += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                plry -= 2
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                plrx -= 2
        if checkcollide(plrx,plry) == 'left':
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                plry += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                plry -= 2
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                plrx -= 2
        if checkcollide(plrx,plry) == 'right':
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                plry += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                plrx += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                plry -= 2
        if checkcollide(plrx,plry) == 'up':
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                plrx += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                plry -= 2
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                plrx -= 2
        if checkcollide(plrx,plry) == 'down':
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                plry += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                plrx += 2
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                plrx -= 2
```

if anybody can help, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That code can't possibly be working as-is -- the return value of `checkcollide()` can't be both a string indicating direction and a boolean.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Of course it can. This is Python, there is no strong typing. I'd agree it's a bad design but it's certainly _possible_.

Comment: Okay, yes. If it were not a string but an object with an overloaded `__cmp__`, agreed that that's *possible*. The OP would need to be going out of their way to make it happen, though, and that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the order of your `if`s:

```
collided = checkcollide(plrx,plry)
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    if collided != 'up':
        plry += 2
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    if collided != 'left':
        plrx += 2
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    if collided != 'down':
        plry -= 2
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    if collided != 'right':
        plrx -= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is an error in your code and what you actually want is to not let the player move in the direction of the collision, rather than the multiple problems with your code (as indented, you do the `checkcollision(plrx, plry) == true` block as well as the rest rather than instead of, and you don't allow for multiple collisions). In this case, your code can be replaced with:

```
check = checkcollision(plrx, plry)
if keys[pygame.K_w] and check != 'up':
  plry += 2
if keys[pygame.K_a] and check != 'left':
  plrx += 2
if keys[pygame.K_s] and check != 'down':
  plry -= 2
if keys[pygame.K_d] and check != 'right':
  plrx -= 2
```

This avoids repeatedly calling your collision check code and also allows for multiple directions being ruled out.

By the way, most game code works by moving the player and then resetting their position, or limiting their movement, if a collision occurs at the new position rather than the check and prevent strategy you've adopted.

Comment: which method is more efficient?

Comment: Usually checking after movement as you have to perform fewer checks but your method could also be made much more efficient by only checking in the direction the player tries to move and only when they press a key.

Comment: @DarkMonolith premature optimisation is the source of all evil.

Comment: @Frogboxe: this isn't "optimisation", it's writing code properly in the first. Knuth's aphorism was never intended as an admonishment against efficiency.